# How to convert an array to an indexed array

Tags: php

I try to convert an array to an indexed array but none of the array functions I found can solve my problem

I have this array

```
Array(
  [no_discount] => 0
  [manufacturers_id] => 2
  [id] => 3
)
Array(
  [no_discount] => 1
  [manufacturers_id] => 1
  [id] => 1
)
```

and I would like to convert this array to

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [no_discount] => 0
    [manufacturers_id] => 2
    [id] => 3
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [no_discount] => 1
    [manufacturers_id] => 1
    [id] => 1
  )
)
```

Is there a simple array function or do I have use a loop?

Comment: Can you not push the arrays directly into empty array? Like this: `$newArr[] = $oldArr1;`

Comment: Your first Array is actually 2 arrays. Could you show how this is created as it may be able to generate it as you want rather than go through a second process.

Comment: Please do not look for a function for each single requirement. Do some programming.

Comment: This question is conceptually flawed. @ronny-linsener, you need to edit your question. You are asking to convert an array (one array) to an indexed array. But the example you are provided is providing two arrays to begin with. So you can either clean the description up, or edit the question's title. What we get from your sample code, `$targetArray[] = $indexedItem` will push each item into the target array using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

loop - or write you own ..

```
$tgt = [];
foreach ( $src as $t) { $tgt[] = $t; }
```

Comment: Aren't you copying the array one element at a time while discarding keys? There is a method for that and I don't think this is what OP asked for.

Comment: This answer and many other answers described here will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are getting your array but will this work for you?

```
        $main_array = array();

        $one = Array(
          "no_discount" => 0,
          "manufacturers_id" => 2,
          "id" => 3,
        );

        $two = Array(
          "no_discount" => 1,
          "manufacturers_id" => 1,
          "id" => 1,
        );


        array_push($main_array, $one);
        array_push($main_array, $two);


        print_r($main_array);
```

Comment: This is basically my comment applied to an example

Comment: This works fine but the original array is created dynamically. These arrays contain the number and details of products in shopping cart

Comment: @RonnyLinsener Show me how you get the original arrays